# Why are my random numbers not changing accordingly in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, random, random-seed

I have some code below that generates some random numbers in Excel:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim RA1 As Variant
ReDim RA1(1 To 5)

For i = 1 To 5

    Rnd (-1)
    Randomize i

    For j = 1 To 5
            
        RA1(j) = Rnd
                             
    Next j
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    
        .Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Value = RA1
        
    End With
    
Next i

End Sub
```

This code basically generates 5 rows of 5 random numbers, but it is not running exactly as it should. When I run this code on my iMac (2021), the random numbers in each row are exactly the same. However, what this code should be generating are 5 different rows of random numbers.

Here is where things become even weirder. When I run this code on my Windows laptop, the output is as desired - that is, I do indeed get 5 different rows of random numbers. I have spoken to my professor about this and he has tried it on his Windows computer too and got 5 different rows of random numbers.

All in all, we basically do not know why my iMac is unable to run this code. Does anyone have any guesses as to why there is this discrepancy here? For example, are there any settings in my iMac's Excel that is preventing my code from running correctly?

Any explanations and solutions will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why not just use the random function or random between function directly in each cell? They change when the sheet is told to recalculate as they are volatile.

Comment: @SolarMike The reason is because this small portion of code is part of a larger macro that I need to run, so I've got to use VBA to do this anyway. The other thing is I need to seed my random numbers, so that, for each i, I have different random numbers, but anytime anyone runs my macro, they should be getting the same set of random numbers each time. The problem now is, when I run this on my iMac, for each i, I am having the same set of random numbers, which is weird. I'm just wondering if anyone knows why it is not running as it should on my iMac when it does on Windows.

Comment: Are you turning off calculation in one of the other macros?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. Because this macro runs for 1000 values of i, I have set calculation to manual in the actual complete macro, but I do use `.Calculate` at every relevant point though? Also, if I may add, there is no “one of the other macros”. There’s actually only one. And if manual calculation is the problem, that still doesn’t explain why the exact code runs just fine on Windows?

Comment: Well you don't have .Calculate in that code you show. And you might want to do some research on here for "Option Explicit"...

Comment: @SolarMike yeah, because I thought `.Calculate` isn’t relevant here in this code per se right? I mean, I tried to run this exact MWE that I posted using Windows and it works just fine. However, you made a good point - I never thought of the `Option Explicit` possibility. I should explore that!

Comment: right `.Calculate` only affects formulas in cells and does nothing to your VBA code. Also `Option Explicit` is something you should always use to avoid issues with variable namings but this also does not solve your issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you described is a bug.

First, if we replace line:

```
Randomize i
```

with:

```
Randomize 0
```

we can see that on Windows we get the exact same repeated values as we would get on a Mac:
[image: image1]

This immediately suggested to me that there can only be 2 possible explanations:

1. Maybe the algorithm is different
2. There is an issue and the value of `i` is not passed/read correctly.

In order to find a rule, I used a separate method (brute-forced i/x) and found the following magic numbers. Again, if we replace line:

```
Randomize i
```

with:

```
#If Mac Then
    Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Array(26489, 63707, 185603, 15365, 92513)
    Randomize i / arr(i - 1)
#Else
    Randomize i
#End If
```

we get the same results on Windows and Mac.

I could not find a clear pattern in those magic numbers so I discarded that the algorithm is different. This left me with finding the issue/bug.

After some trial and error I found that if we pass a `Double` data type to the `Randomize` method it does not read the full 8 bytes but instead only reads the first 4 bytes. That is why dividing by those magic numbers worked, because the resulting numbers (of those divisions) were using the first 4 bytes (including the exponent bits) instead of the 8 full bytes.

The fix is to offset (to the left) the double value by 4 bytes. Here is the final code that works on both Windows and Mac:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Public Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    #End If
#End If

Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim RA1 As Variant
    ReDim RA1(1 To 5)
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        Rnd (-1)
        
        #If Mac Then
            Dim d As Double
            
            d = CDbl(i)
            CopyMemory d, ByVal VarPtr(d) + 4, 4 'Read the last 4 double bytes into the first 4
            Randomize d
        #Else
            Randomize i
        #End If

        For j = 1 To 5
            RA1(j) = Rnd
        Next j
        
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Value = RA1
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

You'll have noticed that I've also added `Option Explicit`, declared all variables and indented the code.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much for this. With my level of VBA knowledge, I would never have been able to troubleshoot to this depth. Would you happen to know if this is a known bug in general with VBA/Excel on Apple, in the sense that VBA/Excel on Apple cannot read 8 bytes? And would this issue surface with other codes (not related to `Randomize`) that will perhaps run just fine on Windows but not on Apple?

Comment: @EthanMark I was not aware of this issue before but it seems isolated to just the ```Randomize``` method and just on Mac. My guess is that the developer who wrote the method simply did not take into account that a ```Double``` is stored in 8 bytes. He probably hardcoded to 4 bytes for whatever reason. You're welcome!

Comment: I see! Also, I did a little more experimenting on my own and realised that, actually, a very simple solution is to move the line `Rnd (-1)` outside of the `i` loop and my code will work on a Mac. In light of this, do you still think the problem has got to do with the 8 bytes and 4 bytes thing that you have mentioned in your answer? Or rather, I guess my question now is, why would moving `Rnd (-1)` outside of the `i` loop fix this "bug"?

Comment: @EthanMark Moving the ```Rnd -1``` outside of the ```i``` loop will give completely different values on rows 2, 3, 4 and 5 compared to your original example. However, because you only set the seed once you get values on subsequent rows but they are not the same with the original ones generated in your example. The bug is still there on Mac. As mentioned before, if the 4 bytes are not fixed then ```Randomize i``` is like ```Randomize 0``` on Mac.

Comment: @EthanMark I tested and I get different values. Maybe post a link to a gist or something so I can see exactly what your new code does. Or post a new question with a link to this one.

Comment: Whoops, you are right. I hadn't looked closely enough. At a glance, they looked similar and I suppose the thing that caught my eye was that the values on my iMac finally changed, so I just (wrongly) assumed they were equivalent to the ones I got on my Windows laptop. I have a different query now though - I don't quite understand the part in your previous reply where you say "because you only set the seed once you get values on subsequent rows". I mean, so why does moving `Rnd (-1)` out of the `i` loop at least give me unique values on my iMac now (though not the same as on Windows)?

Comment: @EthanMark The [Rnd documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function) says that using a negative number in ```Rnd``` sets the same seed everytime. You were previously setting the same seed 5 times and now only once. The [Randomize documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) says that "Using Randomize with the same value for number does not repeat the previous sequence" unless you use an ```Rnd``` with a negative value immediately before.

Comment: @EthanMark You had a different ```i``` for the ```Randomize``` call so you got different row values on Windows but if you were to use the same ```i``` value while doing the ```Rnd -1``` 5 times you would get same row repeated. However using  ```Rnd -1``` just once and then ```Randomize``` with same ```i``` (on Mac was 0 because of the bug) was giving different values.

Comment: But isn’t setting the same seed 5 times and setting that seed just once the same thing? I would think setting the same seed many times over is equivalent to just doing it once (since it is always going to be the same seed). Or is this a misconception?

Comment: @EthanMark it's not the same thing. The ```Randomize``` will behave differently based on how many times you seed the same negative value.

Comment: Oh, okay! Another thing that came across my mind is, since you say that the issue is with a `Double` data type being passed through `Randomize`, I thought that simply declaring `i` as `Integer` or `Long` would solve the problem. However, I tried this and it still doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @EthanMark The function's input is of type ```Variant``` so you can pass anything indeed. But behind the scenes I suspect that whatever you pass (be that Long or Single) actually gets converted/casted to a Double which then inevitably leads to the same bug. I don't think there is any way around it except the fix I found and of course if Microsoft fixes it (which will likely never happen).

Comment: Very interesting indeed! Thank you for all this insightful information :)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the manual of the [Randomize statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) you can find the following:

> *To repeat sequences of random numbers, call Rnd with a negative argument immediately before using Randomize with a numeric argument. Using Randomize with the same value for number does not repeat the previous sequence.*

So I highly recommend to remove `Rnd (-1)` which makes it repeat the sequences of random numbers.

Also try removing the seed from `Randomize i` and just use `Randomize` so the computer takes the system timer as seed (for better random numbers).

---

// Edit according comment

If you need the same numbers everytime but different numbers in all rows/columns then you might need to put the initialisation before your first loop.

```
Rnd -1
Randomize 1 'if you don't need the same seed everytime use Randomize without number

For i = 1 To 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As mentioned, I need to seed my random numbers, so that anyone who uses my macro will have the same results. I was taught to use `Rnd (-1)` and `Randomize i` to do this. If I do not do this, then how can I seed my random numbers? Also, this still doesn’t really explain why this code (as in my post) would work for Windows and not my iMac though?

Comment: @EthanMark Oh I didn't get that you want the same numbers each time. You might need to put the initialisation before your first loop then. See my edit.